# VPC peering between 2 AWS Regions VPC via cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am trying vpc peering between two different region. 
Here I have already created the resources now I just want to pass their ids as parameters. In same region I am able to peer between two VPC. But I am getting error in two different region as route_id does not exist.

[image: Error logs]

My template is below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ''
Parameters:
  PeerVPCAccountId:
    Type: String
    Description: "Peer VPC Account ID"
    Default: (Acc_id)
  PeerVPCRegion:
    Type: String
    Description: "Peer Region"
    Default: (region)
  VPC1:
    Description: VPC Id of DataPipeline
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Default: (vpc_id)
  VPC1CIDRRange:
    Description: The IP address range of DataPipeline VPC.
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: (vpc_range)
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
  VPC1PrivateSubnet1CIDRRange:
    Description: The IP address range for Private Subnet 1 in DataPipeline.
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: (vpc_subnet_range)
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

  VPC1Private1Route:
    Description: RouteTableId of Private Subnet 1 for DataPipeline
    Type: String
    Default: (vpc_subnet_route_id)


  VPC2:
    Description: VPC Id of PII-Isolation Pipeline
    Type: String
    Default: (vpc_id)
  VPC2CIDRRange:
    Description: The IP address range of PII Pipeline VPC.
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: (vpc_range)
  VPC2PrivateSubnet1CIDRRange:
    Description: The IP address range for Private Subnet 1 in PII Pipeline.
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: (vpc_subnet_range)

  VPC2Private1Route:
    Description: RouteTableId of Private Subnet 1 for PII Pipeline
    Type: String
    Default: (vpc_subnet_route_id)

Resources:
  peerRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Principal:
              AWS: !Ref PeerVPCAccountId
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Effect: Allow
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection'
                Resource: '*'

  VPC1Private1PeeringRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock:
        Ref: VPC2PrivateSubnet1CIDRRange
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: VPC1Private1Route
      VpcPeeringConnectionId:
        Ref: myVPCPeeringConnection




  VPC2Private1PeeringRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock:
        Ref: VPC1PrivateSubnet1CIDRRange
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: VPC2Private1Route
      VpcPeeringConnectionId:
        Ref: myVPCPeeringConnection


  myVPCPeeringConnection:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC1
      PeerVpcId:
        Ref: VPC2
      PeerOwnerId:
        Ref: PeerVPCAccountId
      PeerRegion:
        Ref: PeerVPCRegion
      PeerRoleArn: !GetAtt
              - peerRole
              - Arn
```

I have given everything which template want, still showing me this error.
Can someone help modify it or point the mistake?

Comment: You are trying to build two VPCs, with each VPC in a different region? This will not work, because a CloudFormation stack is deployed in only one region. You might consider using [AWS CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html).

Comment: No @JohnRotenstein. I have already two VPCs created. 1 in N Virgnia and 1 in Oregon. Each VPC have 2 private subnets and I want to peer between them. As per that I have giving VPC's id as parameter in CFT template.

Comment: But your template is attempting to create `VPC1Private1PeeringRoute1` (from VPC1 to VPC2) _AND_ `VPC2Private1PeeringRoute1`(from VPC2 to VPC1). You can't do that in the same template because those VPCs are in different regions. You should split the template into two -- one for each region.

Comment: First I want to clarify, you asked: "You are trying to build two VPCs, with each VPC in a different region?" It means You are asking me are you creating two new VPCs in different region in this template?". So it's answer is I already two VPCs created. 1 in N Virgnia and 1 in Oregon. Each VPC have 2 private subnets and I want to peer between them. As per that I have giving VPC's id as parameter in CFT template. You are saying I am attempting to create `VPC1Private1PeeringRoute`. This is just creating route between to different subnets in two different region.

Comment: `VPC1Private1PeeringRoute1` and `VPC2Private1PeeringRoute1 are creating route between two VPCs from a different region for peering. I think, as per this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html) we can do this.

Comment: It looks like `VPC2Private1PeeringRoute1` is trying to define a route "back to" VPC1. However, VPC2 is in a different region, so it cannot be included in the same CloudFormation template.

Comment: So It means you are saying we can not do VPC peering between two different region?

Comment: You can peer between two regions, but if you are doing it via CloudFormation, then you will need one template per "side" -- Template 1 defines VPC1 and should be deployed in Region 1. Template 2 defines VPC2 and should be deployed in Region 2. Each template can only define resources in one region.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, above things I already have setup wherein in region1 with VPC1 is deployed and VPC2 in region2 via different cloudformation templates in both regions. Now I have both VPCs available with me, but how should I initiate VPC peering within these two regions? I mean how should I update route tables of each other -- VPC1 with VPC2 and VPC2 with VPC1 from template. This is what becoming challenging via cloudformation.

Comment: Yes, it sounds challenging! It might require (1) Creation of the VPCs, (2) Creation of the Peering connection, then (3) route tables that use the peering connection. This might help: [Walkthrough: Peer with an Amazon VPC in Another AWS Account - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impurshu, I think there was definitely some confusion regarding understanding that a Cloudformation template can only apply to a single region. However, Cloudformation Stacksets can apply to multiple regions, and I even found an example that applies to your problem [VPC Peering across regions](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/solutions/VPCPeering)

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation deploys resources only in a specific region. For deploying the same resources in different regions you can use CloudFormation StackSet. 
Regarding your scenario, id suggest using CloudFormation to create the necessary resources in one region and also deploy a lambda that will deploy resources in a second region and perform the peering - request, accept and alter RouteTable.
In addition to  the Lambda you'll need to deploy a custom resource to execute the lambda and a Role+Policy for the Lambda (permissions for the actions it will make)